# jQuery initiating many buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to get my head around this probably very simple problem.

I have dynamically generated links, for example #l1, #l2.. and for each link I have a  containing an image img. Divs have IDs corresponding to links, for example #li1, when clicked, should toggle div with id #di1 and so on.

I wrote a test, where I iterate through ID numbers and construct jquery button listeners. Something in the lines of:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]; // those are link and div IDs
for (k=0;k<3;k++){
    $("#"+"li"+a[k]).click(function() {
        $("#"+"di"+a[k]).toggle();
    });
}
```

But what this gives me are listeners on all links, which toggle only the last div!

So again: I have links within a tag, which when clicked, should toggle a DIFFERENT div with corresponding ID.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time `click` is invoked, value of `k` is `3`(because of `k++`), just use `this` context.

Make sure `for-loop` should have `k < 4` condition to iterate `4(0, 1, 2, 3)` elements.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
  $("#li" + a[k]).click(function() {
    $(this).toggle();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="li1">li1</div>
<div id="li2">li2</div>
<div id="li3">li3</div>
<div id="li4">li4</div>
```

Going with *your* approach:

> Use `closure`, inner function remembers the environment in which it is created!

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
  $("#di" + a[k]).click((function(k) {
    return function() {
      $("#li" + a[k]).toggle();
    }
  })(k));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="di1">Div 1</div>
<div id="di2">Div 2</div>
<div id="di3">Div 3</div>
<div id="di4">Div 4</div>
<hr>
<hr>

<div id="li1">Links 1</div>
<div id="li2">Links 2</div>
<div id="li3">Links 3</div>
<div id="li4">Links 4</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, I am trying to toggle a different element here. If I do this, link hides itself perfectly, but nothing happens with the div.

Comment: I obviously wasn't clear enough, I've updated the question. I want links to toggle divs, which are separated elements. In your answers, there are only link divs, which toggle themselves

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `forEach()` as well for cleaner JS code (IMO):

```js
// link and div IDs
var a = [1,2,3,4];
a.forEach(function (v)
{
 $("#li" + v).click(function()
 {
  $("#di" + v).toggle();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li id="li1">one</li>
 <li id="li2">two</li>
 <li id="li3">three</li>
 <li id="li4">four</li>
</ul>

<div id="di1">
 <p>One</p>
</div>
<div id="di2">
 <p>Two</p>
</div>
<div id="di3">
 <p>Three</p>
</div>
<div id="di4">
 <p>Four</p>
</div>
```